# Jenkins Security

Tags: login-screen, jenkins

What is the location for the Jenkins **System Console Output** files? I am configuring Jenkins Security on Ubuntu, and have been locked out at the login screen. Tried every account I can remember but not knowing what is the issue with the id/pwd this feels like the definition of insanity...

Failed Login Message:

> If you are a system administrator and suspect this to be a
>   configuration problem, see the server console output for more details.

Comment: 'console output' sounds like it is actually going to stdout or stderr somewhere, but you might want to start looking in `/var/log/` somewhere or check the syslog/dmesg output.

Comment: If you need any more please PM me or visit AU chat (rep 20+ req. ;) )

Answer (score 3):

The relevant log files can be found at ...

```
JENKINS_HOME:/jenkins.err.log
JENKINS_HOME:/jenkins.out.log
JENKINS_HOME:/jenkins.wrapper.log
```

But I think you probably want to just completely disable security to find out the login and maybe reset the password. In ...

```
/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
```

set `useSecurity` to `false` and you should be able to use Jenkins again and redo whatever got messed up and reset your account. You need to restart the server with `sudo service jenkins restart` too.

---

edit:

Have a look first at `/var/lib/jenkins/users`. The users there are a directory so it should be easier to find your user account. Inside is a `config.xml` that holds an encrypted password for that user.

edit 2: found an article on [resetting password](http://polygoncell.blogspot.nl/2009/02/hudson-forget-password-reset-password.html).